# AES - Pycrypto encryption in python with Crypto decryption in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, cryptography, aes

I've looked at the [AES - Encryption with Crypto (node-js) / decryption with Pycrypto (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236761/aes-encryption-with-crypto-node-js-decryption-with-pycrypto-python) post since I'm trying to do the complete opposite but I can't seem to get it right. Here's what I've tried so far ...

Python encryption

```
import base64
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

text_file = open("cryptic.txt", "w")

pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

plaintxt = 'dolladollabillzz'
iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
print AES.block_size
key = 'totallyasecret!!'
cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
encrypted = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintxt))

text_file.write(encrypted)
text_file.close()
```

Node.js decryption

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

var algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc';
var key = new Buffer('totallyasecret!!', 'binary');

var cryptic = fs.readFileSync('./cryptic.txt', 'base64');
var iv = cryptic.slice(0, 16);
var ciphertext = cryptic.slice(16);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
var decrypted = [decipher.update(ciphertext)];
decrypted.push(decipher.final('utf8'));
var finished = Buffer.concat(decrypted).toString('utf8');
console.log(finished);
```

Every time I try to run the Node.js decryption, I end up with the error message:

```
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the IV is randomly generated in Python, it can contain any possible byte value. Some of those byte values are not valid UTF-8 characters (e.g. multiple bytes are one character) and may result in wrongly sliced off IV, so that the actual ciphertext is slightly shifted.

Since AES is a block cipher, the bits have to line up to be properly decrypted. This should fix it:

```
var cryptic = fs.readFileSync('./cryptic.txt', 'utf8');
cryptic = new Buffer(cryptic, 'base64');
var iv = cryptic.slice(0, 16);
var ciphertext = cryptic.slice(16);
```

This changes a binary string to a Buffer which perfectly handles binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Artjom but I'm still receiving the same 'wrong final block length' error. I've also tried using 'binary' in the readFileSync but the result is the same as well.

Comment: Can you provide a ciphertext for testing?

Comment: Sure, I ran my python script exactly the way it is in my post and came up with the resulting ciphertext

Ew2rBvVohbJdFp9D3rBmIAGQWekoL3W3JuF6sQc4DRQ=