# Encryption (aes-128-cbc) not matching between python(pycrypto) and nodejs(crypto)

Tags: python, node.js, aes, pycrypto, node-crypto

I have got this piece of python code which I need to translate into nodejs. The python code uses pycrypto from encryption. On the nodejs side, I am using the native crypto module. There seems to be a mismatch between the encrypted strings.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from binascii import b2a_hex, a2b_hex
import json

raw_key = [0x58, 0x86, 0x17, 0x6d, 0x88, 0x7c, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0x61, 0x1b, 0xbb, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x28, 0xa4, 0x5a]
key = str(bytearray(raw_key))

raw_iv =  [0x34, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x99, 0x6d, 0x19, 0x3d, 0x28, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0xa2, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x1b]
iv = str(bytearray(raw_iv))

text = json.dumps({ "a": 1, "b": 2 })

cryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
length = 16
count = len(text)
add = length - (count % length)
text = text + ('\0' * add)
encrypted = cryptor.encrypt(text);
print b2a_hex(encrypted)
```

The above python code outputs

```
5c72b1a394654b6dab9ea8fdd90fe56b92141d74cb32ac65ede4d3154801bb57
```

whereas the below nodejs code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const KEY = Buffer.from([0x58, 0x86, 0x17, 0x6d, 0x88, 0x7c, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0x61, 0x1b, 0xbb, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x28, 0xa4, 0x5a]);
const IV = Buffer.from([0x34, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x99, 0x6d, 0x19, 0x3d, 0x28, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0xa2, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x1b]);

const text = JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 });

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', KEY, IV);
cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text, 'utf-8'), cipher.final()]);
console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```

outputs

```
d6a0dbc6df2a1038036e4db985f9ca10
```

Why don't they match? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems you are missing this concatenation on nodejs code: `text = text + ('\0' * add)` ...

Comment: Here you have a good example about the encryption with AES on nodejs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236761/aes-encryption-with-crypto-node-js-decryption-with-pycrypto-python

Comment: But doesn't setAutoPadding(true) automatically adds the missing characters?

Comment: Oh, ok... Sorry. But did you look to the content of the link?

Comment: I would suggest that you change the padding scheme in Python instead of node.js.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

1. Node's automatic padding is PKCS padding. Your python code is using null bytes for padding instead, which is a different format. The [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_autopadding) even explicitly mentions disabling auto padding in order to use null byte padding.
2. The JSON is formatted slightly differently between node and python. Javascript's `JSON.stringify()` removes all unnecessary whitespace, whereas python leaves *some* whitespace (e.g. between elements in an array/object). The easiest solution to this will probably be to change the python code to specify an explicit [`separators` option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump): `json.dumps({ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, separators=(',', ':'))`, since the javascript's `JSON.stringify()` isn't as flexible when it comes to changing the formatting in this way.

The node code below shows that by matching the JSON output *and* using the proper padding, you will get the same hex output as python:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const KEY = Buffer.from([0x58, 0x86, 0x17, 0x6d, 0x88, 0x7c, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0x61, 0x1b, 0xbb, 0x3e, 0x20, 0x28, 0xa4, 0x5a]);
const IV = Buffer.from([0x34, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x99, 0x6d, 0x19, 0x3d, 0x28, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0xa2, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x1b]);

var text = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}';

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', KEY, IV);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);

var length = 16;
var count = Buffer.byteLength(text);
var add = length - (count % length);
if (add > 0)
  text += '\0'.repeat(add);

const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text, 'utf-8'), cipher.final()]);
console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```